# Error in loading .xlsx Data in R: lifecycle’ 0.2.0 is being loaded, but >= 1.0.0 is required

Tags: r, excel, statistics

Whenever I try loading in my Data from an Excel sheet this error message is displayed. I tried multiple Versions and restarted R multiple times. I use the following code:

```r
library(readxl)
Data <- read_excel("C:/Users/Tobia/Desktop/Master Thesis/Data.xlsx")
```

then he shows me this error:

```r
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace ‘lifecycle’ 0.2.0 is being loaded, but >= 1.0.0 is required
```

couln't find any similar problems like this through googling

I tried restarting and updating R, I reinstalled the tidyverse package.

Comment: Have you tried installing the latest version of `lifecycle` package? Try `install.packages('lifecycle')`

Comment: Tried it but sadly yields the same results after